# multiple definitions, how to prototype std::map?

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

I know what is going on, but I don't know how to fix this:

main.cpp

```
#include "Win32.h"

int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

Win32.h

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <map>

#ifndef WIN32_H_
#define WIN32_H_

namespace W32 {

class Win32;                        // Pre-Declaration
std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;  // Handle to Class instance mapping

class Win32 {
    public:

        Win32();
        virtual ~Win32();

    protected:

    private:

};  // Class Win32

} // namespace W32

#endif // WIN32_H_
```

Win32.cpp

```
#include "Win32.h"


namespace W32 {

Win32::Win32() {
}

Win32::~Win32() {
}

} /* namespace W32 */
```

Error Messages:

```
    src\Win32.o: In function `Win32':
    D:\Dev\Projects\Eclipse\OpenGL3\Debug/../src/Win32.cpp:7: multiple definition of `W32::windowMap'
    src\main.o:D:\Dev\Projects\Eclipse\OpenGL3\Debug/../src/main.cpp:14: first defined here
```

Ok, I get it that `std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;` is appearing in more the one file, and that because it is included in more then one file (main.cpp/Win32.cpp) it is causing it to be redefined.  I am still somewhat new to std::map.  What I need to do is prototype `windowMap`, but what I don't know is how?  I thought this was when I grabbed this piece of code.  The Win32 class needs to be able to use it, but it will have to be declared in order to do so, but what I have is not the way to do it, I am at a loss on what to look for to get the right information on how to properly forward declare `std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap`.

Comment: Does any other code, apart from `Win32`, need to use `windowMap` ?

Comment: About using global instances of non-POD types like `std::map`, you may want to read [this point](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Static_and_Global_Variables) of Google C++ style guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;
```

is a definition, so you're breaking the **one definition rule**. You need to make the variable `extern`:

```
extern std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;
```

and define it in a single implementation file:

Win32.h

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <map>

#ifndef WIN32_H_
#define WIN32_H_

namespace W32 {
   class Win32;                        // Pre-Declaration
   extern std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;  // Handle to Class instance mapping
   //...
};  // Class Win32

} // namespace W32

#endif // WIN32_H_
```

Win32.cpp

```
#include "Win32.h"
namespace W32 {
   std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;  // Handle to Class instance mapping
   //...
} /* namespace W32 */
```

Comment: `extern`, learn something new everyday.   Fixed.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The following is a *deifnition*, not a *declaration*:

```
std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;
```

Definitions go in cpp files; in the header you need a *declaration*, like this:

```
extern std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;
```

The definition

```
std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap;
```

should go in the cpp file. Otherwise, each cpp file that includes the header with a definition will define its own `windowMap`, resulting in a linker error that you see.

Answer (score 0):

The pure C++ method is to make:

```
std::map<HWND, Win32 *> windowMap"
```

a `static` member of Win32 class. In addition, forget about the `file.h` alongside with `file.cpp`, it has been deprecated by nearly every hardcore developer for sake of simplicity. Your code is so short, so everything should be included in the header, in especially when programming frameworks as you seems to do.

Your problem pop's up the reason why static members exists in C++. Furthermore defining this map `extern` is not good practice, cause you will also have to hide the real definition somewhere, maybe in a not so relevant place.

And finally, I've tried this design already, Windows handler's function get called in an asynchronous way ...

1- You will run in a race condition if more than one window is active at the same time.

2- In fact you'll run a race condition as soon as you call `CreateWindow` function, since it makes a call to your windows message pumping handler, in your back, and you don't know the `HWND` value yet

3- You will run a race condition if you try to `insert/read/remove` in the map at the same time, a quite common operation in fact.